# Integrate leaflet module in a google maps application

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, leaflet

Is it possible to use a leaflet application over a google maps application?

What I want is to integrate a leaflet module / application over a google maps application just by passing the google maps DOM element to my leaflet module and not just change the leaflet module baselayer.

Is it a way to do that?

I was thinking to create 2 distinct maps and "share the events" like the mouse interactions but I don't know if it could work.

Comment: Do you want to use leaflet with the google maps API, or do you want a google basemap in your leaflet app?

Comment: I created a leaflet based application / module and I want to make possible for someone working on a google maps application to import my module and display it over his map. There is no basemap in my module.

Comment: Only the "share the events" method would work, because Google Maps API and Leaflet uses completely different objects in structure (and as long as I can see, you want to share objects and variables between the two APIs). Sorry, if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I don't want to share any variables and objects between the two maps. I just want my map to be able to display over the google maps. The thing is that both maps should respond the same way to users inputs so that we can't notice that there is 2 distinct applications.